# Symfony 3.4: Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I'm new to Symfony. I'm following a course, and after creating a new Symfony project, they use this console to create new bundle `php bin/console generate:bundle`

But when I do this in the console, and then use `php bin/console server:run`, it throws an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "HomeBundle" from namespace "HomeBundle".
>
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? 
>   
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony_CRUD\app\AppKernel.php:19

After a lot of time searching for solution, almost i just found "change composer.json" solution, but it already fixed composer.json at Symfony 3.4 , so i don't know what to do next.

Here is my composer.json at the beginning

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.5.9"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

> AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new HomeBundle\HomeBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(function (ContainerBuilder $container) {
            $container->setParameter('container.autowiring.strict_mode', true);
            $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);

            $container->addObjectResource($this);
        });
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

> My code tree:

[image]

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Look like you have an unknown class in your AppKernel.php line 19.
Can you show your AppKernel ?

Do you have a bundle called HomeBundle ? maybe you remove it ? Your composer.json look ok

Comment: yes i will, please stand by, thanks for reading :)

Comment: i've edited the post, please check :) by the way, this is totally a new symphony project, so i don't think AppKernel have any problems :)

Comment: Please note for future questions that the framework you are using is called Symfony, and not Symphony (which is an unrelated CMS). Thanks :) I've edited the question and tag.

Comment: Yes, thanks for telling me that :) I'll remember for the next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I see now, you should change this in your composer.json, from :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
   "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

to

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
   "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

Like this you add to the composer autoloader (`vendor/autoload.php`) all php class inside src/ of your project

After this you need to recreate your autoload file:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: After i changed this, do i have to do something else, like `composer install` or something? thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I edited my post, you need to regenerate the `vendor/autoload.php` by composer install or dump-autload :)

Comment: ah i found the way to do this, run
`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: if you run composer update it will generate all assets again and it will run